# A C# filestream function, which should return a set of double coordinates

Tags: c#, filestream

I made this function to return two coordinates and a name from a text file. Everything works, however I seem to be getting two `integers` instead of `doubles` when I try to use these coordinates in another function. Below is the actual code and the output when using a getter.

Examples from input file:

```
delfshaven 51.9229006954, 4.43681055082
delfshaven 51.9229377766, 4.43726467466
```

Code:

```
public void ReadCoords(string path, string naam)
{
    string line;
    int endname;
    int endfirstcoord;
    int i;

    string name;
    string coord1;
    string coord2;
    double north, east;

    var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line != "")
            {
                i = 0;
                while (line[i] != ' ')
                {
                    i++;
                }
                endname = i;
                name = line.Substring(0, i);
                i++;
                if (naam == name)
                {
                    while (line[i] != ',')
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                    endfirstcoord = i;
                    coord1 = line.Substring(endname + 1, i - 1 - (endname));
                    coord2 = line.Substring(i + 2, line.Length - (i + 2));
                    north = double.Parse(coord1);
                    east = double.Parse(coord2);

                    deelgemeente.Add(new PointLatLng(north, east));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
{Lat=519226886783, Lng=443421830655}
{Lat=519227198819, Lng=443459846581}
{Lat=51922824973, Lng=443591425503}
{Lat=519228427681, Lng=443610117779}
{Lat=519229006954, Lng=443681055082}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show your input file.

Comment: Where are you generating the string output for the generated `PointLatLng`-Objects? Using your code to generate the objects works for me. Having overriden `ToString` to return the following: `return string.Format("{{Lat={0}, Lng={1}}}", Lat, Lng);` the output is correct, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I got the fix. The problem was occurring because of my local laptop settings. It was having troubles with casting a string to a double.

```
north = double.Parse(coord1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
east = double.Parse(coord2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

instead of

```
north = double.Parse(coord1);
east = double.Parse(coord2);
```

fixed it.